# How to develop a fastest road website?

Tags: routing, network, road

I need to develop a website to find the fastest road between two points (just like google map)
What kind of technologies I need to use? What are the components of this project (database, website, etc)? What else do I need to consider?

Comment: Google have spent millions of dollars for fast integrated server farms, the 'cheap' alternative is OpenRouteService http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenRouteService#Components_of_ORS

Comment: or OSRM or graphhopper (disclaimer: I'm the autor of the latter one)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use ESRI Technology you'll need [network data set](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_is_a_network_dataset/004700000007000000/)  at your data base. The second important component is server and a application for this You'll need [ArcGIS Server](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Welcome_to_the_ArcGIS_10_1_for_Server_Windows_Help/0154000002np000000/) to publish it to the internet. and a website.

Answer (score -1):

If you want it to be independent of other websites, then you'll need the data describing the street network for your area, software for doing the route calculations and software for showing it on a map.

But what is the purpose of the website? Tell us, for which purpose, how many users, which area etc. Generally, why don't you use Googlemaps, if it should be like that?

Comment: the purpose of the website is not only to show best directions in the current time, but also in the future. For example, if there is an event will happen in a specific road like workroads and I decided to travel in three hours I can know by using this website and also know an alternative directions. I hope I've explained clearly.

Comment: You can use our RW NetServer software for the routing calculations and keep several different networks available, for different times of day. It is also possible to change the speed of single sections, while the server is running. You will need a data source for the street network in your area (commercial, free, perhaps you have it in-house). And finally software for displaying it on the server (many, many are available).